# Why does my Azure Functions project not recognize classes from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http assembly?

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions

I have an Azure Functions project targeting `netcoreapp3.1`. The project references another Class Library project (also targeting `netcoreapp3.1`) that uses the `FormFile` class from the [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/) assembly.

The Class Library project compiles and tests run through the code successfully but when I run the Azure Functions project I get the following exception:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.FormFile' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

**My question is** why is the azure functions project unable to load the class and how can I fix it?

---

Here is the project file for the Azure Functions project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <AssemblyName>AzureFunctionsProject</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>AzureFunctionsProject</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SendGrid" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="3.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.7" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibraryProject.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And the project file for the Class Library:
ClassLibraryProject

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>ClassLibraryProject</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>ClassLibraryProject</RootNamespace>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="..\.editorconfig" Link=".editorconfig" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.35" />
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper.Contrib" Version="2.0.35" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" Version="2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" Version="4.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="1.0.19269.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="3.1.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Running `dotnet --list-runtimes` outputs:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Comment: Fixed it by replacing, in the Class Library project, the package reference on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` with `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />`. Will promote to an answer later in the day unless anyone wants to beat me to it :)

Answer (score 1):

So the root cause of my problem was twofold:

1. My Class Library project was referencing the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` nuget package. This package is not compatible with .NET Core 3.0 and above.
2. My code was using the class `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.FormFile` which is not available in .NET Core 3.0 and above. (It moved to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.FormFile`)

ASP.NET Core 3.0 introduced the concept of the *shared framework*. This is implemented by the [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` metapackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app?view=aspnetcore-3.1) which made a large number of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` nuget packages redundant. (But not all of them)

**To fix the problem:**

1. I removed this nuget package reference from the Class Library's project file:

   ```
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" Version="2.2.2" />
   ```

   and replaced it with this framework reference:

   ```
   <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
   ```
2. In files where I was using the `FormFile` class, I change this using statement:

   ```
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal;
   ```

   to this using statement:

   ```
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If may I ask why are you using FormFile on Azure Functions?

What I would suggest to you is basically use Azure Functions with Blob Trigger - Not HttpTrigger. And you get the file as `Stream` on Blob Trigger.

If you are writing an API (or you especially need HttpTrigger for some reason), you can get the file over `HttpRequestMessage` with HttpTrigger. You can create `MultipartMemoryStreamProvider` and read as multipart (like enctype = multipart/form-data in HTML forms) and read as byte array or whatever you want to process.

Please find the example code block below:

```
[FunctionName(nameof(UploadFile))]
public static async Task UploadFile([HttpTrigger(Constants.AuthorizationLevel.UploadFile, 
Constants.HttpVerbs.UploadFile, 
Route = Constants.Routes.UploadFile)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    var streamProvider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
    await req.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);
    var firstFile = streamProvider.Contents.First();
    var fileInfo = firstFile.Headers.ContentDisposition;
    var fileData = await firstFile.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

    // e.g for image 
    var img = new Image()
    {
        FileName = fileInfo.FileName,
        Size = fileData.LongLength,
        Status = ImageStatus.Processing
    };
};
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @mehmet-taha-meral. That doesn't answer my question. The file is not related to the function's trigger. Please consider the `FileInfo` as an internal requirement inside the function. The problem is that the class library project is using a .net core 2.1 DLL (`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http`) but the azure functions project is targeting .net core 3.1.